# Finding Out the Centroid of a Polygon

Tags: geometry

**I am trying to learn how to apply the mathematical formula for finding out the centroid of a polygon.**

Doing some research, I found out the following formulae that might be useful:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid

If I understand correctly, finding out the centroid first requires determining (i.e. approximating) the area of a polygon and then the centroid.

Suppose I have a 2 dimensional polygon and the coordinates for the boundary - I think I could use the following formulae:

$$A = \frac{1}{2} | \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i y_{i+1} - x_{i+1} y_i) |$$

$$C_x = \frac{1}{6A} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} ((x_i + x_{i+1}) (x_i y_{i+1} - x_{i+1} y_i))$$

$$C_y = \frac{1}{6A} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} ((y_i + y_{i+1}) (x_i y_{i+1} - x_{i+1} y_i))$$

Using the R programming language, I generated a random polygon:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
# Create a data frame with random coordinates

x <- rnorm(20, mean = 0)
y <- rnorm(20, mean = 0)
df <- data.frame(x, y)

# Add some random noise to the coordinates
df$x <- df$x + rnorm(nrow(df), sd = 0.3)
df$y <- df$y + rnorm(nrow(df), sd = 0.3)

# Sort the points in a clockwise order
df <- df[order(atan2(df$y, df$x)),]

# Add the first point to the end of the data frame to close the polygon
df <- rbind(df, df[1,])

# Plot the polygon
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_polygon(fill = "lightblue", color = "black")
```

[image]

I then tried to apply these formulae to find out the area and the centroid:

```
# Calculate the area of the polygon
n <- nrow(df) - 1
A <- 0.5 * abs(sum(df$x[1:n] * df$y[2:(n+1)] - df$x[2:(n+1)] * df$y[1:n])) 

# Calculate the x and y coordinates of the centroid
Cx <- (1 / (6 * A)) * sum((df$x[1:n] + df$x[2:(n+1)]) * (df$x[1:n] * df$y[2:(n+1)] - df$x[2:(n+1)] * df$y[1:n]))
Cy <- (1 / (6 * A)) * sum((df$y[1:n] + df$y[2:(n+1)]) * (df$x[1:n] * df$y[2:(n+1)] - df$x[2:(n+1)] * df$y[1:n]))


#Area:  4.200753 
#Centroid x:  0.08894211 
#Centroid y:  0.05408409 

# Plot the polygon with centroid point
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_polygon(fill = "lightblue", color = "black") +
    geom_point(aes(x = Cx, y = Cy), color = "red", size = 3)
```

[image]

Although this red point looks like the centroid - I am not sure if I am correct.

**Can someone please tell me if I have understood this correctly?**

Thanks!

Comment: Looks correct to me. However, in RHS of formulas of $C_x$, $C_y$, you need to multiply them by the sign of what's inside $|\cdot|$ on RHS of formula of $A$ (or equivalently, get rid of the $|\cdot|$ in definition of $A$ and use $A$ to denoted the signed area of polygon).

Comment: @  achille hui: thank you so much for your reply! If you have time, can you please show me how to correct this - just so I can be clear that I have correctly understood you? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the image into `Mathematica` and extrapolate the coordinates of the polygon:

```
img = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVoIa.png"];
lines = Cases[Normal@ListContourPlot[Reverse@ImageData[img], Contours -> 1], _Line, -1];
data = Reverse@SortBy[lines[[All, 1]], Length];
```

then translate and scale the coordinates in an artisanal way:

```
data = Transpose[data[[1]]] - First[data[[1]]];
max = {Max[data[[1]]], Max[data[[2]]]};
pts = Transpose[{1.39, -1.59} + data {0.90, 3.45} / max];
```

finally visualize everything by calculating the area and centroid of the region:

```
poly = Polygon[pts];
Graphics[{LightBlue, poly, Red, Point[RegionCentroid[poly]]},
          Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, GridLines -> Automatic]
{Area[poly], RegionCentroid[poly]}
```

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

> {4.32459, {0.0829052, 0.0506929}}

Due to the manual translation and rescaling, the results don't match, but they're still very similar!

---

On the other hand, formulations of this kind you can make yourself with **Gauss-Green theorem**:

$$
\iint\limits_D \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\right)\text{d}x\,\text{d}y = \int\limits_{\partial^+D} f(x,y)\,\text{d}x + g(x,y)\,\text{d}y
$$

in which cleverly choosing the functions $f,g$ (there're infinitely many equivalent ways) leads to:

$$
A = \int\limits_{\partial^+ D} x\,\text{d}y,
\quad \quad
S_x = \int\limits_{\partial^+ D} -\frac{y^2}{2}\,\text{d}x,
\quad \quad
S_y = \int\limits_{\partial^+ D} \frac{x^2}{2}\,\text{d}y,
\quad \quad
(x_c,y_c) = \left(\frac{S_y}{A},\frac{S_x}{A}\right).
$$

In particular, parameterizing `n`-line segments along a closed loop as:

$$
(x(t),y(t)) = \left(x_i + (x_{i+1}-x_i)t, \; y_i + (y_{i+1}-y_i)t\right)
\quad \quad \text{with} \; t \in [0,1]
$$

by integrating, we get the formulations:

$$
A = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\left(x_{i+1}+x_i\right)\left(y_{i+1}-y_i\right)}{2},
\quad \quad \quad
S_x = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\left(y_{i+1}^2+y_{i+1}y_i+y_i^2\right)\left(x_i-x_{i+1}\right)}{6}, \\
S_y = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\left(x_{i+1}^2+x_{i+1}x_i+x_i^2\right)\left(y_{i+1}-y_i\right)}{6}
$$

which can be immediately verified with a code like:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {10, 2}];
ord = FindShortestTour[pts];
pts = pts[[Last[ord]]];

poly = Polygon[pts];
{Area[poly], RegionCentroid[poly]}

{A, Sx, Sy, n} = {0, 0, 0, Length[pts]};
{x, y} = Transpose[Join[pts, {First[pts]}]];
Do[A = A + (x[[i + 1]] + x[[i]]) (y[[i + 1]] - y[[i]]) / 2, {i, n}];
Do[Sx = Sx + (y[[i + 1]]^2 + y[[i + 1]] y[[i]] + y[[i]]^2) (x[[i]] - x[[i + 1]]) / 6, {i, n}];
Do[Sy = Sy + (x[[i + 1]]^2 + x[[i + 1]] x[[i]] + x[[i]]^2) (y[[i + 1]] - y[[i]]) / 6, {i, n}];
{Abs[A], {Sy/A, Sx/A}}
```

> {10472.4, {10.4885, -29.511}} 
> {10472.4, {10.4885, -29.511}}

where the perfect correspondence with the results of `Mathematica` is evident (the absolute value is just because I didn't care about the counterclockwise order of the dots, otherwise it's unnecessary).

All this to invite you to try and experiment, it's always better to derive the formulas! ^_^